# ¿Por que me sale none al ejecutar una funcion?

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en programación y haciendo ejercicios de funciones, frecuentemente me encuentro que al correr el programa, me devuelve el resultado que yo quiero pero acompañado de un none debajo.

```
  def notacion_doce_horas(hora, minutos):

      hora_equivalente = hora-12 # para horas mayores a las 12 AM
      if 1 < hora < 12:
        pass
      if 13 < hora < 24: 
        print(hora_equivalente, ":", minutos, " PM")

      return print(hora, ":", minutos, " AM")

  notacion_doce_horas(0,12)
```

Comment: Para hacer un print no es necesario hacer un return, si quitas el return probablemente te dejará de aparecer el None

Comment: Lo he hecho y sigue saltando none

Comment: Tienes algo más de codigo aparte de lo que has mostrado? He probado tu codigo y una llamada a ese codigo y no me aparece ningun None

Comment: el resto del codigo son las variables minutos y hora (metidas dentro de bloques try y except para rechazar valores que no sean 0 < hora < 24 o 0 < minutos < 59. (estan fuera del subprograma notacion_doce_horas)

Comment: Fijate que probando esto en un IDE online: https://repl.it/repls/ConstantCapitalConnections no aparece el None. Por lo pronto te diría que el problema no está en el método, nose si puede ser la versión de Python que utilizas o algo del código adicional que te está generando el None

Comment: a mi tambien este codigo me tira NONE
No se si la solucion seria buscador = search(text, word)
print (buscador)
o no ? text = input ()
word = input ()
def search (text, word): if word in text: print ('Word found') else: print('Not found')
print(search(text,word))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Posiblemente estés tratando de imprimir el resultado de llamar a `notacion_doce_horas()`, es decir que en tu programa hayas escrito algo como:

```
print(notacion_doce_horas(11, 23))
```

En cuyo caso verás como resultado "11:23 AM" en una línea y `None` en otra.

Esto se debe a que `notacion_doce_horas()` en realidad retorna `None`, pues tal como lo tienes en tu pregunta:

```
return print(hora, ":", minutos, " AM")
```

está retornando el resultado del `print()`, y `print()` retorna `None`  (además de imprimir lo que le mandes). Por tanto sale el `11:23 AM` impreso por el `print()` que hay dentro de tu función, y luego sale el `None` impreso por el `print()` del programa principal, que estaría imprimiendo lo retornado por la función.

Esto no se arregla quitando el `return` de la función y dejando solo el `print()` pues, si bien en este caso ya dejarías de retornar le valor `None` retornado por el `print()`, interno, aún así la función llegaría a su final sin haber retornado nada, por lo que Python hará que retorne un `None` implícito (es decir, una función que termina sin retornar nada explícitamente, retorna también `None`). Así que seguirías viendo el `None` en la salida.

Todo esto proviene de un error de diseño. Tu función `notacion_doce_horas()`, para ser útil en diferentes escenarios, **no debería imprimir nada** y después retornar None, sino que debería retornar la cadena transformada al formato que quieres. Y ya el programa principal se ocupará de imprimir esa cadena, si lo que quieres es verla en pantalla. Este enfoque permite usar la función para otros propósitos distintos de mostrar por pantalla el resultado (por ejemplo, podría servir también para guardarlo en fichero, pues la función realmente sólo crea la cadena y es el programa principal quien decide qué hacer con ella).

Es decir, deberías cambiar los `print()` por `return`  de la cadena apropiada. Por ejemplo:

```py
    return "{}:{} AM".format(hora, minutos)
```

Si no conoces la función `format()` o prefieres no usarla, también puedes crear la cadena resultante concatenando sus partes:

```py
    return str(hora) + ":" + str(minutos) + " AM"
```

Answer (score -1):

He tenido la misma dificultad que tú y sugiero que prescindas del print antes del return, con eso tu algoritmo correrá y no tendrás más ese valor 'none' al final de tu ejecución. Por otra parte bien haces en suprimir print de la instrucción notacion_doce_horas(0,12).

Answer (score -1):

Estas ejecutando el code en modo interactivo, no es necesario el print. Ya esta implicito. print(print()) retorna None. Saludo